# Direct targeting element attribute value when deserializing

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have a given xml file that looks roughly like this:

```
<InstanceID val="0" xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/AVT/">
    <TransportState val="PLAYING" />
    <CurrentPlayMode val="SHUFFLE_NOREPEAT" />
    <CurrentCrossfadeMode val="0" />

    <!-- The actual xml has about 20 elements, 
         all elements have a val attribute. -->
</InstanceID>
```

I'ld like to deserialize this xml without having to create a class for each element. Is there a way to directly read the 'val' attribute from each element?
At this moment I have classes like this:

```
[XmlRoot("InstanceID", Namespace = "urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/AVT/")]
class AVTransportEventData
{
    [XmlElement("TransportState")]
    public List<TransportState> TransportState { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("CurrentPlayMode")]
    public List<CurrentPlayMode> CurrentPlayMode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("CurrentCrossfadeMode")]
    public CurrentCrossfadeMode CurrentCrossfadeMode { get; set; }
}

public class TransportState
{
    [XmlAttribute("val")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class CurrentPlayMode
{
    [XmlAttribute("val")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class CurrentCrossfadeMode
{
    [XmlAttribute("val")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

This sucks. It should be more something like this fake code:

```
[XmlRoot("InstanceID", Namespace = "urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/AVT/")]
class AVTransportEventData
{
    [XmlElement("TransportState"), [XmlAttribute("val")]
    public string TransportState { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("CurrentPlayMode"), [XmlAttribute("val")]
    public string CurrentPlayMode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("CurrentCrossfadeMode"), [XmlAttribute("val")]
    public string CurrentCrossfadeMode { get; set; }
}
```

Each element will only occur once and I only need the 'val' attribute value. 
Is this possible? Or does it give more solutions?

Comment: If it's ok to use LINQ2XML or XmlReader you can read just the values without deserializing the XML using LINQ2XML or XmlReader. An example can be found [in this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756567/deserialize-arbitrary-xml/19757396#19757396).

Comment: Solved it using ExpandoObjects. Thanks for showing me being blinkered.
I used the article [Creating a dynamic object from XML using ExpandoObject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/461677/Creating-a-dynamic-object-from-XML-using-ExpandoOb) as a starting point.